# Javascript + Imacro Random Wait Time Between Steps and Loop Sections Of Code Bug

Tags: javascript, random, imacros

There are some imacro with Javascript questions on here, but nothing that gave me what I need... I tried this question: [Imacros: Random wait time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13801272/imacros-random-wait-time) and this question: [How to loop only a series of steps in iMacros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17959454/how-to-loop-only-a-series-of-steps-in-imacros) (this was helpful, but now what I have is a bit buggy).  I can't figure out why this isn't working...

What I want to do is follow people on Tumblr using imacros.  I added the `Math.random()` function because I want it to choose a random amount of time within 0 to 11 seconds in which it follows a new person.

I only want the imacro to run this part of the code once because it only needs to be run once:

```
window.location = "URL GOTO = https://www.tumblr.com/search/pony/recent" + "\n";
var rand = "Math.random()*7 + 5";  
var macro = "CODE:SET !REPLAYSPEED FAST" + "\n";
var macro = "CODE:SET !ERRORIGNORE YES" + "\n";
macro += "TAG POS={{i}} TYPE=I ATTR=CLASS:icon_view_list&&TXT:" + "\n";
```

Then I want it to loop this part of the code (the actual following steps):

```
macro += "TAG POS={{i}} TYPE=DIV ATTR=TITLE:Like&&CLASS:post_control<SP>like&&TXT: " + "\n";    
macro += "WAIT SECONDS={{rand}}";
```

It loops it using this:

```
for(var i=0;i<100;i++)    
{
iimDisplay(i);    
iimSet("i", i);    
iimSet("rand", rand);    
iimPlay(macro);
}
```

This works well except these lines of code: `macro += "TAG POS={{i}} TYPE=I ATTR=CLASS:icon_view_list&&TXT:" + "\n";` and `var rand = "Math.random()*7 + 5;"` do not seem to be working properly.  The first part of code is to make it so it selects the "list view" instead of the "grid view" on tumblr because I cannot get the grid view to work (if anyone has any insight as to why it doesn't work that'd be great, but not a big deal).  The second part of the code isn't working properly because it will always set `rand` to 11 seconds... so it looks like the `Math.random()` function isn't working properly and I cannot figure it out.

Here's my entire code:

```
window.location = "URL GOTO = https://www.tumblr.com/search/pony/recent" + "\n";
var rand = "Math.random()*7 + 5";  
var macro = "CODE:SET !REPLAYSPEED FAST" + "\n";
var macro = "CODE:SET !ERRORIGNORE YES" + "\n";
macro += "TAG POS={{i}} TYPE=I ATTR=CLASS:icon_view_list&&TXT:" + "\n";
macro += "TAG POS={{i}} TYPE=DIV ATTR=TITLE:Like&&CLASS:post_control<SP>like&&TXT: " + "\n";    
macro += "WAIT SECONDS={{rand}}";
for(var i=0;i<100;i++)    
{
iimDisplay(i);    
iimSet("i", i);    
iimSet("rand", rand);    
iimPlay(macro);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`var rand = "Math.random()*7 + 5";` returns a string, surely

Try:

```
    window.location = "URL GOTO = https://www.tumblr.com/search/pony/recent" + "\n";

    var macro = "CODE:SET !REPLAYSPEED FAST" + "\n";
    macro += "CODE:SET !ERRORIGNORE YES" + "\n";
    macro += "TAG POS={{i}} TYPE=I ATTR=CLASS:icon_view_list&&TXT:" + "\n";
    macro += "TAG POS={{i}} TYPE=DIV ATTR=TITLE:Like&&CLASS:post_control<SP>like&&TXT: " + "\n";
    macro += "WAIT SECONDS={{rand}}";
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        var rand = Math.random() * 7 + 5; //<--rand should be inside the loop
        iimSet("i", i);
        iimSet("rand", rand);
        iimPlay(macro);
        iimDisplay(i);
    }
```

EDITED to move the rand inside the loop. Sorry, my bad.

Comment: I realized one problem, but have not been able to fix it.  The reason that the code does not create a new random number each time it loops is because it only sets the random number once due to `var` being in front of the command.  How can I make it so it runs with the other code that has `macro` in front?  If I remove the `rand`, then I don't have a place holder for `iimSet("rand", rand)`.  Do you see?  I could put `iimPlay(rand)` above `iimPlay(macro)`, however is there a better way?

Comment: UPDATE: Tried the above, but now it doesn't recognize `rand` because it is not defined...